# Git does not detect a remote branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I have cloned a repository (from gitlab if relevant)
I got the repo in my local machine, the branch being *master*

I want to checkout to another branch *another_target*

I can ***clearly*** see that this branch exist in the remote repo.
However when I do

```
git checkout another_target
```

I got

```
error: pathspec 'another_target' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Just to check I do

```
git branch -r
```

and no! the branch another_target does not appear!

But I can see it in the repo!

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Do `git fetch` first? Maybe you did a single branch clone?

Comment: Thanks! I found out the probable cause. The branch exists only on a forked version

Answer (score 3):

To update your remote branches you should first run

```
git fetch
```

then your `checkout` should work if the remote branch exists

Comment: Additionally you probably want to add the `--prune` flag when fetching to remove any references to deleted remote branches in your local repository.